# Error: Formula `mongodb-community` has not implemented #plist, #service or installed a locatable service file

Tags: mongodb

I kept getting this error even when I installed on root directory

I was using the   `brew services start mongodb-community@4.2`

```
Error: Formula `mongodb-community` has not implemented #plist, #service or installed a locatable service file
```

Comment: Is 4.2 the installed version?

Answer (score 2):

I looked to the documentation at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/

I was able to successfully start mongoDB by following these steps

Uninstalled
`brew untap mongodb/brew && brew tap mongodb/brew`

Install
`brew install mongodb-community@5.0`

Start `brew services start mongodb-community@5.0`

Outlog:

```
==> Successfully started `mongodb-community` 
(label: homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community)
```

Comment: This is not working, do you have any other solution